# how to draw a donut (ring) shape using quad?

Tags: lua, 3d, draw, shapes, ring

quad => quad(Vector1, Vector2, Vector3, Vector4)

it mean

```
V1 ------------------- V2
l                       l
l                       l
l                       l
l                       l
l                       l
V3---------------------V4
```

how to draw ring shape using quad function?

is it possible?
if it's so hard, someone tell me how to draw cone using quad function?

Comment: Are you using some kind of library or software to draw your ring? Which one? We will need a lot more information to be able to answer this. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry, but i'm using GLUA(Garrys mod lua) not lua, it's smilar but little different